# Is there a Extent Reports support for Ready API/ SoapUI NG Pro?

Tags: soapui, extentreports, extent

I want to generate Extent Reports for SoapUI tests. I do not want to use plain old frames based JUnit HTML Report that SoapUI offers. Does Extent Reports support this? An example would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```groovy
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

def failedTestCase = 0;
def extent = new ExtentReports("C:\\SampleReport.html",true)
runner.results.each {
  testCaseResult -> def name = testCaseResult.testCase.name
  def extentTest = extent.startTest(name, name)
  if(testCaseResult.status.toString() == 'FAILED'){
    failedTestCase++
    extentTest.log(LogStatus.FAIL, testCaseResult.testCase.name)
  } else {
    extentTest.log(LogStatus.PASS, testCaseResult.testCase.name)
  }

}
```

Comment: How did you implement extent reports in soapUI ? steps would be helpful.. Thanks

Comment: it is throwing me error "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: runner for class: Script14 error at line: 14" Please help!

Comment: How to add steps for each test case? if we need to capture assertions of the test  cases?